# Visual Studio Error Cant open source code of my form

Tags: error-handling, runtime-error

[image: Here is the picture]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMzUp.png)

I was working on my project about 4 hours and after I am done with it I saved it and try to rename the form name bu mouse right click ! after that it gave me like that error even I cant open my source code :( is there any why that can I save my codes at least. 
in addition : when I press build it builds with no problem and I can use it.

Comment: did you change the form4 name in the project !

Answer (score 0):

I guess there was an visualstudio error, It changed the form name but didn't update successfully to the .csproj file. You can fix this issue by opening the .csproj file and edit it (by notepad or any text editor) or unload project and edit it, find the name of Form and mame sure the path to the form and form name is correct

Hope this helps!